# Google Document List API - Get Collection or Item by its path?

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I'm currently developing a google drive client. [This](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/) documentation describes how to access collections or items by their ID. But how is it possible to get an item by its path?

For example, I want to get a file /documents/pictures/sunshine.png. How can I get this file withouth knowing its ID?

Comment: Can you give an example of a "path"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current version of the API, it is not possible to directly access a file by filename. This limitation is due to the fact that a user can have multiple files having the same name in the same folder.

The only way to get access to a file is by its ID. The path is not necessary as the file's metadata contains parentsFolder information.

Comment: so.. I would have to make 3 requests to get the ID of sunshine.png and then another one to read its contents? Isn't this very slow? I mean... holding a list of all files in memory is very expensive in memory. I can't do this for a large amount of users :/

Comment: Why would you make 3 requests to get the ID of sunshine.png? From a web app, you can simply fire up a [Picker UI](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open#open_files_using_the_google_picker) which will let the user choose the file. Once the file is chosen, the ID will be passed to the callback and what you're app will have to do is send one request to get the metadata, and another one for the data (if requested).

Answer (score 2):

Alian, I have the same feeling with Van Coding. I my application I just use google doc as a document database.

I do not want to expose google doc UI to my customer. If user want to edit a file, what I did is download that file with html format and display it in a html editor.

I most time I just know a file name (beacuse it is more sensitive for a user than a resouceID) and need find this file in google doc. So if I could access a file via a path would be much convenience.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [the google docs api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#getting_a_list_of_documents_and_files) , and search by the title parameter ,  if you have some documents made with some application in drive this will be returned the document, i think you have to add the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file to get the authorization.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Document ID by looking at the URL. For example, if I have a document open in the browser and the URL is:

https://docs.google.com/a/apps.kingsacademy.edu.jo/document/d/1tb6oqih33k1BhadraHNdozizAB7kok-8WRHo_35xeVA/edit

Then the Document ID is: 1tb6oqih33k1BhadraHNdozizAB7kok-8WRHo_35xeVA